# OOP - Call function containing instance of class within the same class

Tags: python-3.x, function, class, oop, instance-variables

I am new to programming and have done some research on instance, class, and static variables. Lately, I have tried to simplify my code on my projects to help me learn more in Python. In this particular instance, no pun intended, I'd like to be able to call the somefoo() function that will assign arguments to the **init** instance variables one and two, depending on conditions. From my understanding, in order to call the somefoo() function, the Foo() class must be instantiated; however, the parameters the class requires are within the somefoo() function within that class. Thank you in advance!

```
import random
    class Foo():
        def __init__(self, one, two):
            self.foobar = random.random()
            self.one = one
            self.two = two

        def somefoo(self):
            if self.foobar > 0.5:
                one = ':)'
                two = 1
                Foo(one, two)
            if self.foobar < 0.5:
                one = ':('
                two = 0
                Foo(one, two)

        somefoo()
```

Comment: you've got the right idea, instantiate the class, and call the class methods. instead of calling `Foo(one, two)` set those member variables using `self`, see here:  https://pastebin.com/raw/nDb72CDy

Answer (score 0):

To begin with, I don't even know if you have **checked** your code before posting it here for help because there is something really wrong with it. There are lot of **syntax mistakes**. This is how it's supposed to be...

```
import random
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, one, two):
        self.foobar = random.random()
        self.one = one
        self.two = two

    def somefoo(self):
        if self.foobar > 0.5:
            one = ':)'
            two = 1
            Foo(one, two)
        if self.foobar < 0.5:
            one = ':('
            two = 0
            Foo(one, two)

somefoo()
```

There were **parenthesis** before the **class name** which were not **required** in python along with **useless indents**. Python is **sensitive** when it comes to indents so make sure your indents are meaningful, and use them logically. Now coming to your question; here is how it can be done:

```
import random
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, one, two):
        self.foobar = random.random()
        self.one = one
        self.two = two
        self.somefoo()

    def somefoo(self):
        if self.foobar > 0.5:
            self.one = ':)'
            self.two = 1
        if self.foobar < 0.5:
            self.one = ':('
            self.two = 0
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.one)+" "+str(self.two)
print(Foo(10,20))
```

Basically the part where you are trying to call **somefoo** is not wrong and yes python does execute the class down to the bottom when it makes a object of it in memory, but in your code the method is of **bound type** (i.e. it **needs and object** for execution). So what you can do is use some sort of **object factory pattern**, or go with the one I have pasted above, in which as soon as object is generated, it calls the bound method which swipes the data of instance in question and displays the output. In **python3 unbound methods** are introduced which can be used without the **self object reference**. Make sure you look into them too and how they work, as they may help you to come with more flexible solution to your problems.